# dependent formula columns in oracle reports

Tags: oracle, report

In oracle reports, I have a scenario where I have 2 formula columns A,B in a group G. A computes a value and stores it in placeholder column C in the same group G.

Given A&C are defined above B, Would B always see the value C updated by A?. I have a couple of test cases where B sees the updated value. Just wanted to make sure that this is the defined order of execution in oracle reports.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the SRW.REFERENCE procedure to make sure that a PL/SQL block will be executed **after** the object referenced are computed. From the help topic:

> **Description**  This procedure causes Report Builder to add the referenced
>   object to the PL/SQL construct's
>   dependency list.  This causes Report
>   Builder to determine the object's
>   value just before firing the PL/SQL
>   construct.  This is useful when you
>   want to ensure that a column value
>   passed to a user exit is the most
>   recently computed or fetched value.
>
> **Syntax** SRW.REFERENCE (:object CHAR|DATE|NUMBER);

Comment: Thanks. If I understood this correctly I have to do something like this,(please correct me if I am wrong)  
In Formula B,
srw.reference(:a);
srw.reference(:c);
This would make sure that B sees the latest C.

Comment: Could you please suggest a link where I can see the Syntax of all the methods in SRW package?. Google search yields a couple of blog results which are blocked where I work :-(

Comment: @komedit1: use the help from Reports Builder (F1), it contains the description of all SRW procedures and functions and working examples.